# Django Reverse with arguments '(5,)' not found

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have created a view that accepts 3 arguments but I get the following error in the homepage.

> Reverse for 'application-detail' with arguments '(5,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[0-9]+)/devices/(?P[^/]+)$']

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.MapView,name='home'),
    path('map/',views.MapView,name='map'),
    path('<int:application_id>/devices/<cat>', views.ApplicationDetail, name='application-detail'),
]
```

View:

```
def ApplicationDetail(request, application_id,cat):
        device = Device.objects.all().filter(category=cat)
        data = serializers.serialize('json', device)
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: And where error happens? You used `reverse` method somewhere in code, right?

Comment: Try adding a `/` at the end of your url definition.

Comment: What is the url you are hitting?

Comment: In base template i have : `<a  href="{% url 'applications:home' %}">Organization</a>`

Comment: @Andd it's not happening in your base template. You are somewhere else using something like this `{% 'application-detail' ...` and the ID you passing is a tuple instead of single integer.

Comment: @Charnel well the debugger was highlighting that line but ur correct. Error is here: `<form action="{% url 'applications:application-detail' application.id %}" method="POST">`

Comment: I will end up creating another url pattern for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to pass `cat`: `{% url 'applications:application-detail' application.id cat %}`, where `cat` is you cattegory (idk how you named it in template)

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely calling the `reverse` function somewhere in your code like:

```
reverse('application-detail', args=(5))
```

However, the `path` for `reverse` takes two arguments, an `int` (`application_id`) and a `string` (`cat`) and thus, when calling reverse, you must also provide the `string`, e.g.:

```
reverse('application-detail', args=(5, 'super cat`))
```